# Using link_to to write a value to an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a model for POs (purchase orders) and one of its attributes is status. I'm trying to write a link_to which will write the value "closed" to the status of the currently open PO.

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Close PO', {:action => :update, :method => :patch, :id => @po.id, :status => 'closed'} %>
```

This doesn't work so far, as the link brings me back to the PO show view and the status of the current PO remains "open". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think your `link_to` would look more like:

```
<%= link_to 'Close PO', po_path(@po, po: {status: :closed}), method: :patch %>
```

This assumes, naturally, that your `routes.rb` includes:

```
resources: :pos
```

Comment: The model is called po, so I've adapted your proposed code. But it reports a SyntaxError: /app/views/pos/show.html.erb:67: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting ')' ...h(@po, status: :closed) method: :patch );@output_buffer.safe... ... ^

Comment: Sorry, try a comma after the closing parenthesis (updated answer).

Comment: Getting closer, but now: param is missing or the value is empty: po

Comment: My po controller has this:     def po_params
      params.require(:po).permit(:date, :vendor_id, :note, :is_recurring, :status)
    end

Comment: Right. You could force it with `po_path(@po, po: {status: :closed})` which should give you a url something like `po/1?po%5Bstatus%5D=create`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That worked! The final working code as follows:     <%= link_to 'Close PO', po_path(@po, po: {status: :closed}), method: :patch %>